# Why is my round-robin simulation in omnet++ not working?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

I am new to omnet++. To get familiar with it, I am trying to simulate a simple round-robin scheduling in a ring topology with "n" number of nodes. It compiles fine, but the simulation itself doesn't run as expected. Ideally, it should show "n" number of nodes in a ring topology and a message should be sent and processed to them starting node1. This is what the NED file looks like:

```
import ned.DelayChannel;


module Node
{
    parameters:
        double cpuClock = 500;
        double memsize = 512;
        int numCores = 1;

    gates:
          inout out[];
          connections allowunconnected:
}

network RingTopology
{
    parameters:
        int numNodes = 4; // number of nodes in the ring
        
    types:
        channel RingChannel extends ned.DelayChannel
        {
            delay = 1us;
        }

    submodules:
        node[numNodes]: Node {
            @display("p=100,100;i=device/cpu_s");
            gates: out[2];
        }

    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..numNodes-1 {
            node[i].out[0] <--> DelayChannel <-->  node[(i+1)%numNodes].out[1];
        }
}
```

This is what the C++ file looks like:

```
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class RingTopology : public cSimpleModule
{

    public :
        RingTopology() : tasks {8, 6, 36, 88, 15, 14, 46, 29, 30, 5, 93, 43, 68, 65, 20, 69, 49} {}

    private:
        int numNodes;
        int cpuClock;
        const int numTasks = 17;
//        const int numTasks;
        int currentTask;
        int tasks[];

    protected:
        virtual void initialize() override;
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

class Node : public cSimpleModule
{
    private:
      int numNodes;
      int numCores;

    protected:
      virtual void initialize() override;
      virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};


Define_Module(RingTopology);

void RingTopology::initialize()
{
    numNodes = par("numNodes");
    cpuClock  = par("cpuClock");
    currentTask = 0;
}

//void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
void RingTopology:: handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
        // Round-robin scheduling
        if (currentTask < numTasks-1)
            currentTask++;
        else
            currentTask = 0;

        // Calculate time slice based on task time and CPU speed

        int SIMTIME_HZ = 1000000000;
        simtime_t cpuClock = SimTime(500.0, SIMTIME_US) * SIMTIME_HZ;
        double taskTime = tasks[currentTask] * 1.0; // convert taskTime to double
        simtime_t timeSlice = taskTime / cpuClock;  // divide taskTime by cpu clock to find the number of seconds required to finish the task


        msg->setKind(1);
        send(msg, "out", currentTask % numNodes);
        scheduleAt(simTime() + timeSlice, msg);
    }
    else {
        // Message from another node, process it
        handleMessage(msg);
    }
```

}

And the .ini file looks like this

```
[General]
# nothing here

[RingTopology]
network = RingTopology
```

When I run the simulation, the simulator window looks like this [image: Image: The simulator window when I run the above code]

Please, let me know how to fix this and what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation is not working because in `initialize()` you do not send neither a self-message nor a message.
However, even if you added sending the missing message, your code would raise an error. Focus on the following lines:

```
send(msg, "out", currentTask % numNodes);
scheduleAt(simTime() + timeSlice, msg); // will raise an error
```

The message (more precisely: pointer to a cMessage object) must not be used after sending. Take a look at [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual - chapter 4.7.3](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:broadcasts-and-retransmissions):

> A message is like a real-world object -- it cannot be at two places at the same time. Once sent out, the message no longer belongs to the module: it is taken over by the simulation kernel, and will eventually be delivered to the destination module. The sender module should not even refer to its pointer any more.

Comment: And a few other issues: RingTopology is a Network type (i.e. a compound module). It does not require C++ implementation as it defines only topology. On the other hand, Node would require C++ implementation (you shared only the header file), and the Node definition in NED must be `simple Node` instead of `module Ned`.

I suggest to take a look at the TicToc tutorial because you are seemingly missing a few concepts to create a running simulation.